# Submit a page from mobilefirst hybrid application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have a page of an external application. I want to submit that page with username/pswd from mobilefirst hybrid application. My mobile application is single page Jquery Mobile based application. I tried window.open it works in browser preview but it does not work on a device.

For Security reasons, do not want to use GET or query string to pass variables along with URL. Just want to do POST and want to open it in a mobile browser while mobile app keeps on running at the back end.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In order for Mobile Browser to open. You have to include `_system` inside `window.open` like example below

```
window.open(URL, "_system")
```

Comment: This works only with GET protocol. But I need to call URL with method=post and have to pass the variables.